# Sum of string integers in array - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

In postgres DB, I have a jsonb column which has a data in string array, like:

```
{
 "name": "john doe",
 "testData": "["1", "2", "3", "", "", ""]"
}
```

I want to convert string `testData` to array and then those string integers to int and then sum them up.

```
select sum(ARRAY(test_column->>'testData')::int) as sum from table;

Output -> "6"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have properly formatted JSON, then you can extract the array and sum the non-empty values:

```
select *
from t cross join lateral
     (select sum(nullif(el, '')::int)
      from jsonb_array_elements_text(t.x->'testData') el
     ) s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=55cca751b09faffbf2dd2e27d53c2c67) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that you describe the data structure as "a string array".  But you have an extra set of quotes, so it is really "a string that looks like a string array".

Comment: That's right @Gordon_Linoff, it is string that looks like string array. I just checked your fiddle and you might need to insert the testData in this form: "["1", "2"....]"